# How to build and install spark in an offline environment?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to install Spark 1.3.1 in an offline clusters (No Internet at all, only Lan). However, I don't know how to build it from source code since either via maven or sbt requires network connection. Can someone offer some help or possible solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simply (albiet somewhat hacky) solution would be to build it on a machine with internet access and then copy all of the items in ~/.ivy2 over to the machine with only lan access so that it can access the cached items. Another, perhaps simpler, option would be to use a pre-built Spark is thats an acceptable solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I don't want to use prebuilt one due to I may need to change the Spark source code.

Comment: Makes sense, in that case you can always look at the make-distribution scripts in the spark project to make the jars your self. Anyways hope one of these approaches ends up working for you :)

Comment: well, it turns to be a lot more complicated. I am trying to use mvn to build but received a lot of network unreachable even though I copy all the cached data under ~/.m2 folder. I am wondering if it is the same that I compile and build the spark in an internet accessible machine and then copy the whole folder to the No-internet one. Would that be the same ?