# how to compile Spark in offline environment

Tags: apache-spark

I have two machines that have installed the same OS (RedHat 6.5 64bit), but with different hardware configurations. Machine 1 (denoted as `M1`) has network access and Machine 2 (denoted as `M2`) doesn't have network access. `M2` has more powerful hardware (e.g., more CPU cores and more memory). Now I want to setup a `Spark` environment in the `M2`.

I have downloaded the `spark-2.0.0-preview` from the official github repository. And I try to compile it, but it doesn't work because of no network access. After googling, I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493926/how-to-build-and-install-spark-in-an-offline-environment). So I turn to the `M1` to compile the `spark-2.0.0-preview` package. The compilation command is `./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package`. It shows `BUILD SUCCESS`. Then I copied the whole `spark-2.0.0-preview` directory and the `~/.m2/*` in `M1` into the corresponding positions in `M2`.

In `M2`, I can run `./bin/run-example SparkPi`, which I think the built library in `M1` can also be run OK in `M2`. But when I run the command `./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package` to try to build the localization library in `M2`, it shows a error:

```
    [info] Error occurred during initialization of VM
    [info] java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
    [info]  at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    [info]  at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1166)
    [info] 
    [error] Compile failed at May 19, 2016 1:43:09 AM [0.425s]
```

I realize that if the `clean` in the command leads to the problem. The `clean` means that `mvn` will delete the temporary files during the previous compilation. Thus I try another command `./build/mvn -DskipTests package`. But the error still exists.

I have two questions:

1. Will the built `spark-2.0.0-preview` library in `M1` be suitable in `M2`?
2. Is there any compilation command that can keep all the temporary files when compiling the `Spark`? So we can simply copy all the files into another machine to reuse them.